# I wish to hide either one Row or another row in excel Depending on a value

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently using vba to automate a proposal, and if its overseas, there will be a different price than if it is domestic. So I created a code to automate hiding a row that has the overseas price or the domestic price, depending on if you input 0 or any other number in an input box on a different sheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If .Worksheets("Price Estimator").Range("v5").Value = "0" Then
    Rows("5").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Else
    Rows("6").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
End Sub
```

It currently is doing nothing. Where should I go from here?

Comment: `.Worksheets("Price Estimator").Range("v5").Value =0`. `"0"` is a string `0` is a number.

Comment: remove the `.` in front of `Worsheet("P...`

Comment: The new first line is `If Worksheets("Price Estimator").Range("v5").Value = 0 Then`

Still nothing

Comment: if `Worksheets("Price Estimator").Range("v5")` this cell is empty ?

Comment: I think you need to reconsider your method here.  If you hide row 5, then you can't update `V5` to ever trigger the code again... You might want to consider using the `Target` range object which represents the cell that changed and use `If Target.Column = "V" And Target.Value = 0 Then` instead of what you already have?

Comment: @Dave: Read the first paragraph again. The value is being input on a different sheet than the one where the rows are being hidden.

Comment: My bad - it's late here :)

Comment: Just to clarify - again, it IS late here so I might have missed something (else) but this code will be fired when a cell is changed on the worksheet the code is attached to.  If you make a change on another worksheet (to change `V5` on `Price Estimator`) it's certainly not going to fire this worksheet_change event...

Comment: @cyboashu, not its not, I could make it true or false, yes or no, or anything, I just thought typing in 0 or a number ie 1, would be simpler to code.

Comment: @Dave is right. You should clarify what sheet change should trigger what sheet row hiding

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
With Worksheets("Price Estimator")
If .Range("V5").Value = 0 Then
    .Rows("5").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Else
    .Rows("6").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
end with
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```